# cypress configuration error when plug is created as an import rather than as a const in cypress.config.ts file

Tags: typescript, cypress

i am new to cypress so please bear with me if this a trivial issue.
below is my cypress.config.ts file. i am trying to add cypress esbuild preprocessor to the configuration.

```
import cypress_esbuild_preprocessor from '@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor';
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        cypress_esbuild_preprocessor(),
      );
    },
  },
});
```

if i fire up cypress, below configuration error shows up on the console-

```
TypeError: (0 , cypress_esbuild_preprocessor_1.default) is not a function
```

works fine if i create cypress_esbuild_preprocessor as a const like so-

```
const cypress_esbuild_preprocessor = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor');
```

since i a using typescript for coding i want to create the plugin as import rather than as const.
version of cypress - 12.17.1

any thoughts greatly appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

fixed this by setting `"esModuleInterop": true` under tsconfig.json's compilerOptions.